# Determining the first available value in a list of integers

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I got a simple List of ints.

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>();

myInts.Add(0);
myInts.Add(1);
myInts.Add(4);
myInts.Add(6);
myInts.Add(24);
```

My goal is to get the first unused (available) value from the List.

(the first positive value that's not already present in the collection)

In this case, the answer would be 2.

Here's my current code :

```
int GetFirstFreeInt()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; ++i)
    {
        if(!myInts.Contains(i))
            return i;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("All integers are already used.");
}
```

Is there a better way? Maybe using LINQ? How would you do this?

Of course here I used ints for simplicity but my question could apply to any type.

Comment: Is list sorted by ascending order?

Comment: @OsmanTuran Nope. The list isn't guaranteed to be sorted in any way. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You basically want the first element from the sequence `0..int.MaxValue` that is not contained in `myInts`:

```
int? firstAvailable = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                                .Except(myInts)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit in response to comment:**

There is **no** performance penalty here to iterate up to `int.MaxValue`. What Linq is going to to internally is create a hashtable for `myInts` and then begin iterating over the sequence created by `Enumerable.Range()` - once the first item not contained in the hashtable is found that integer is yielded by the `Except()` method and returned by `FirstOrDefault()` - after which the iteration stops. This means the overall effort is O(n) for creating the hashtable and then worst case O(n) for iterating over the sequence where n is the number of integers in `myInts`.

For more on `Except()` see i.e. Jon Skeet's EduLinq series: [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 17 - Except](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-17-except/comment-page-1/)

Comment: Nice, but what if myInts contains {0,1,2,3} ? I would need the method to return 4 in that case.

Comment: @asmo: Ah that wasn't clear from the question - in that case use int.MaxValue as upper bound not `myInts.Max()` - I will update the answer.

Comment: @asmo Make it `myInts.Max() + 1`

Comment: @Lester: Then you have the edge condition if myInts.Max() is already int.MaxValue

Comment: @BrokenGlass True, but I think it's worth adding a check for that specific case in order to avoid (possibly needlessly) enumerating 2 billion integers.

Comment: @Lester: see updated answer - there is no performance penalty since the outer sequence is lazily enumerated and only until the first unused integer is found.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a nullable int? Won't the default value be 0, not null?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the list is ordered from smallest to largest and contains values from 0 to positive infinity, you could simply access the i-th element. `if (myInts[i] != i) return i;` which would be essentially the same, but doesn't necessitate iterating through the list for each and every `Contains` check (the Contains method iterates through the list, turning your algorithm into an O(n-squared) rather than O(n)).

Comment: +1. Yes, and if the list is unsorted it is faster to sort it before doing GGulati's test. Sorting is O(n*log(n)), which is faster than O(n^2) for the iterated Contains check. (If I am right, Microsoft is using QuickSort.)

Comment: Sorting won't be faster than using a HashSet which is O(n) for OPs problem